# jQuery Chosen plugin query

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-chosen

I am using chosen plugin for a multiple select and I want to dynamically display all the selected options somewhere in the page.

I am able to show them, however, I also want to remove them if someone deselects/removes them. This is what I am struggling with.

My code till now looks like

```
$(".chosen-select").chosen({max_selected_options: 5}).change(function() {
    var bStr = "#home-summary-right";
    var htmlContent = $("#home-summary-right").html();

    $(".search-choice").find("span").each(function() {
        $(bStr).html("" + htmlContent);
        toAppend = '<span>' + $(this).text() + '</span>';
        $(bStr).append(toAppend);
    });
});
```

**Okay**

Otherwise, is there any way to disable removing of elements once they are select in the multiple select? There is that cross, to which I can do display none, but I still don't know how can i disable the backspace from removing the elements.

Comment: Please add the html code as well or create JSFiddle to elaborate more.

Comment: The html code is just like

<select class="chosen-select">
<!-- Bunch of values -->
</select>

and the other div is empty at the beginning

Like

<div id ="home-summary-right">
</div>

Comment: does this similar plugin do what you want without messing with the html? http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/  the multiple select seems to remove the item fomr the list when selected.  I might have the wrong end of the stick here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I fixed it.

I used setTimeout in combination with bunch of other things.

The problem was after change, the inner html would return the same content as before... So I called an event after pretty much everything was done. Works super smooth!